# "un début de semblant de ...": Is this an acceptable pleonasm?

Tags: emphase, humour

> Grâce à vos explications, je viens de trouver **un début de semblant de** solution à mon problème !

Normally, I separately use either of "un début de" or "un semblant de" to express the idea of making do with what little you are given at the moment, as in.

> même pas **un début de** piste
>
> retrouver **un semblant de** vie normale

I wonder if it is considered an acceptable pleonasm to juxtapose these two phrases with overlapping meanings to further emphasise the idea?

Even so, I assume this dual phrasing only works when the noun in question {*solution*} can be coupled with both "un début de" and "un semblant de" individually to begin with. Since you don't say "*retrouver un début de vie normale*", I wonder if the following doesn't sound odd:

> retrouver **un début de semblant de** vie normale

Incidentally... Does it work the other way round as well?

> trouver **un semblant de début de** solution

Answer (score 3):

It sounds very acceptable to me, the pleonastic phrasing in this case gives a slightly humorous tone, and stresses that this is just the very beginning of something. I would still refrain from using it in formal writing.

As you suggest, the other way round ("semblant de début") is also acceptable.

You can even add more nouns to stress even further the idea that you are in the very modest and early stage of something:

"Cette enquête donne un semblant de début de chouia de réponse"

"J'ai senti un début de semblant de frémissement d'intérêt de sa part"

Comment: *Au début du commencement, il n'y avait que le pléonasme. Il n'y avait pas le plus petit début de semblant d'un prototype de quoi que ce soit d'autre. C'en était redondant de vide et de néant autours de ce pléonasme formant la matrice du rien de rien. Puis, lorsque le commencement commença à commencer, le pléonasme engendra le reste de l'univers en une gigantesque émanation ultra-méga répétitivement redondante de quelques ingrédients reproduits à l'infini.*

Comment: Ça ne fait pas l'ombre de la moitié d'un doute